# What is this key on the Microsoft 5050 Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, macbook

What is this key on the Microsoft Wireless Comfort 5050 Desktop keyboard?

I would like to map it for use on a  Mac (with Karabiner, built-in mapping, or some other tool), but can't even find what it is called.

[image: special control key]

Comment: It looks a lot like the task switch function from Windows 10, and given this is a Microsoft keyboard with loads of bells and whistles, I would not be surprised, that it will open the task switch view when pressed.

Comment: Can it be mapped? Using Karabiner, no keypress event is recognized when I type it.

Comment: I honestly don't know. I don't have access to such keyboard and every software that handles keypress mappings does it differently. Some programs can handle the craziest keys while others can only handle some. It really depends on how this button does what it does. If for example the button requires the signal to be interpret by the driver in order to give it an action, then you need to have a driver installed before you can do anything with that key. In other cases it may send a keystroke, but you should be able to detect that.

Comment: More than likely it is a Windows feature, since Microsoft has no MAC driver for it, only Windows, maybe it is monitor screen orientation toggle, >>>>>>https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/wireless-comfort-desktop-5050/pp4-00001#techspecs-connect